# How to avoid creating an infinite loop when calling bash inside of bashrc with BASH_ENV set?

Tags: bash, cron, bashrc

Inside of `~/.bashrc`, I run a bash script (a script with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the top). I have found that when `BASH_ENV` is set to my `~/.bashrc` that this sets up an infinite loop when a bash command is run. What is the best way to avoid this?

Here is my understanding of what happens (see also [the bash manual on startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)):

1. `bash` run non-interactively resolves `BASH_ENV` to `~/.bashrc`.
2. `bash` begins sourcing `~/.bashrc`.
3. `bash` gets to the line in `~/.bashrc` that calls the bash script and starts a `bash` subprocess.
4. The `bash` subprocess resolves `BASH_ENV` to `~/.bashrc` and so goes back to step 1 here, setting up an infinite loop.

I came across this issue because I wanted to run some cron jobs using my standard environment and found suggestions to set `BASH_ENV` within the crontab. I am posting this as a question here because I couldn't find the issue discussed in my searches online and it seems like something could bite others. I am posting my own solution below, but there may be better ones.

Answer (score 3):

At the top of `.bashrc` put:

```
unset BASH_ENV
```

If `.bashrc` is already being sourced to set up the environment, there is no need for future calls to `bash` to set up the environment again.